# Darle la gana vs venir en gana

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos

Both of these expressions in essence seem to mean doing ‘whatever you like’ or ‘as you please’ in a selfish/self-centred kind of way.

Is there a difference in emphasis between the two? Is one considered more colloquial than the other, or more offensive?

Does the meaning or emphasis change significantly if used in the negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dar la gana se usa cuando no quieres hacer algo, no es ofensivo pero puede resultar basto/grotesco. Venir en gana se traduciría como apetecer, pero en este caso es un lenguaje más fino, típico de círculos profesionales.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de encontrar esta interpretación tambien, https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/venirse-en-gana.133766/ creo que ahora entiendo la diferencia bastante bien

Answer (score 1):

Creo que son dos expresiones distintas

- Dar la gana / "Me da la gana" - Expresa una voluntad de querer ó no querer hacer una cosa con una actitud normalmente de cabezonería, terquería u obstinación.
- ¿Por que te pones ese pantalón? - Porque me da la gana
  *En este caso es una aptitud en que se impone la voluntad del que lo expresa*.
- Venir en gana -  Se trata más bien de un antojo ó un deseo, dependiendo del tono también se puede percibir como un capricho con el que no se puede razonar. Darle a uno ganas de, tener el deseo de hacer algo o que alguien haga algo por que esa es tu intención.
- ¿Por que te pones ese pantalón? - Porque me vino en gana.
  En este caso expresa un deseo "*repentino*".

Espero que te haya ayudado
Diego M

Answer (score 0):

Both are practically identical in emphasis. I would personally say that **'darle la gana'** is a tiny bit more offensive than **'venir en gana'**. But that is just my personal context of usage of the expression. For another person it could be the opposite.

When used in the negative, neither the meaning nor the emphasis changes. If anything, I would say the same as before: **'no me da la gana'** a tiny bit more offensive than **'no me viene en gana'**. But could vary from person to person.